# Perform styling on a string in Android

Tags: android

I would like to perform operations such as changing the color, underline, or bolded a string in my code.

```
String str= "Article 1\n";

QUOTES = new LinkedHashMap<>();
QUOTES.put(str);
```

how can i apply this on my string?

Comment: The simplest thing is to use HTML markup in the string, then use `Html.fromHtml()` to create a `CharSequence` with the formatting that you can put into a `TextView`. A string itself has no formatting.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice thing called [Spannable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable), which helps to style your text.
We're using it to change colors, underlines, selections, clickable words, icons inside the text, etc.

For example, color of a specific word can be changed in this way:

```java
TextView productDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productDescription);

Spannable spannedDescription = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");        
spannedDescription.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 5, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

productDescription.setText(spannedDescription);
```

There's a lot more options to play with.
I suggest you to read this cool [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568) by Florina Muntenescu.
Spannable is quite a powerful and easy-to-use tool, especially when writing apps with kotlin :)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not an Android developer. That being said, there is nothing you can do to change the styling of the string by modifying the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these properties in the XML, or change the TextView properties.
Example:

```
mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
mTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.<name_of_color>));
```

**EDIT 1** 
If you need to store such information. Use a class like this:

```
public class DecoratedString {

    private String text;
    private Color color;
    private boolean isBold;

    //**Constructor
    //**Other methods

}
```

Comment: The problem is that this string is not contained in an XML file, it's just a string that I use in my java code.

Comment: Strings don't have properties like color and bold. These properties is from some sort of rendering. But if you need to store these properties, you just need to create a class with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spannable` to style your text (color part of string, underline, strikethrough, part of string as a link etc) For more details: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable